# Copy / Duplicate / Clone GitHub Milestone & All Linked Issues

Tags: github

I'm new to using GitHub for project / release management. Historically used Jira for this. I'd like to setup some milestones as "template releases", including numerous standard tasks (issues) intended to be performed on all releases. Obviously, each release will likely have other specific tasks for that release, but would like to cut down on manual creation of the standard issues performed each release every time I need to create a milestone (as a release). For this to work, would need an easy way to copy / duplicate / clone a milestone and all linked issues so that the release could be started from this "template milestone" and linked issues. I've done a little Googling but striking out. I've already setup templates for issues, but looking for a better way to efficiently use the milestones feature to manage releases. Or is there another good way to handle this?